# Mingw64 cannot link with glfw because gdi32 functions are missing

Tags: c, gcc, gdi, glfw, mingw-w64

I'm trying to compile the following program in Main.c:

```
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>


int main()
{
    glfwInit();

    return 0;
}
```

I compile it with:

```
gcc -m64 -c -g -I"libs/vulkan/include" -I"libs/GLFW/include"  -std=c11 -MMD -MP -MF "bin/main.o.d" -o bin/main.o src/Main.c
```

and link it with:

```
gcc -m64 -o bin/vulkanfirsttest.exe bin/main.o -L"libs/vulkan/lib" -L"libs/GLFW/lib" -L"C:/msys64/mingw64/lib" -lvulkan-1 -lglfw3 -lgdiplus
```

It compiles successfully but when I try to link it, it spits out the following errors:

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libs/GLFW/lib/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):(.text+0x8e): undefined reference to `__imp_CreateDCW'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libs/GLFW/lib/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):(.text+0xc8): undefined reference to `__imp_GetDeviceCaps'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libs/GLFW/lib/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):(.text+0x123): undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteDC'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libs/GLFW/lib/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):(.text+0x263): undefined reference to `__imp_GetDeviceCaps'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libs/GLFW/lib/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):(.text+0x88b): undefined reference to `__imp_GetDeviceCaps'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libs/GLFW/lib/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):(.text+0x9db): undefined reference to `__imp_GetDeviceCaps'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libs/GLFW/lib/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):(.text+0xdaa): undefined reference to `__imp_CreateDCW'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libs/GLFW/lib/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):(.text+0xdb9): undefined reference to `__imp_GetDeviceGammaRamp'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libs/GLFW/lib/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):(.text+0xdc2): undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteDC'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libs/GLFW/lib/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):(.text+0xf37): undefined reference to `__imp_CreateDCW'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libs/GLFW/lib/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):(.text+0xf46): undefined reference to `__imp_SetDeviceGammaRamp'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libs/GLFW/lib/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):(.text+0xf4f): undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteDC'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libs/GLFW/lib/libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):(.text+0x21a): undefined reference to `__imp_CreateDIBSection'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libs/GLFW/lib/libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):(.text+0x253): undefined reference to `__imp_CreateBitmap'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libs/GLFW/lib/libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):(.text+0x304): undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteObject'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libs/GLFW/lib/libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):(.text+0x397): undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteObject'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libs/GLFW/lib/libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):(.text+0x432): undefined reference to `__imp_CreateRectRgn'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libs/GLFW/lib/libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):(.text+0x4ab): undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteObject'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libs/GLFW/lib/libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):(.text+0x16a): undefined reference to `__imp_SwapBuffers'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libs/GLFW/lib/libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):(.text+0x42d): undefined reference to `__imp_ChoosePixelFormat'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libs/GLFW/lib/libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):(.text+0x43b): undefined reference to `__imp_SetPixelFormat'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libs/GLFW/lib/libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):(.text+0xc97): undefined reference to `__imp_DescribePixelFormat'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libs/GLFW/lib/libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):(.text+0xe81): undefined reference to `__imp_DescribePixelFormat'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libs/GLFW/lib/libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):(.text+0xe9b): undefined reference to `__imp_SetPixelFormat'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libs/GLFW/lib/libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):(.text+0x1498): undefined reference to `__imp_DescribePixelFormat'
```

I found a post that had a similar problem, and the answer was to also link gdi32, but there isn't a gdi32 package in mysys2. There is gdiplus (mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-libgdiplus 5.6.1-1), but as you can see that doesn't help.

Comment: You have to link against gdi32: `-lgdi32`

Comment: I don't know how but it worked, thanks a bunch!